# Scroll wheel zooms when using Loop Cut And Slide

Tags: mouse

here I'm on Windows 10 with Blender 2.8. Before the update, when using *Loop Cut And Slide* I could use the scroll wheel to alter the number of cuts, and after clicking I could move the cut to the desired position. Additionally, after the click I had left the Loop tool and could straight work on and select another vertice or whatever. Now, with Blender 2.8, this tool just proposes a cut in the middle of the focused edge, and the scroll wheel just zooms in and out. I need to click the number of cuts in the helper dialog, and to leave the tool I need to click another tool like *Select*. That's horrible and slows down my workflow enormously.

More strange: The *Loop Cut And Slide* tool on my computer at work (Manjaro Linux and Blender 2.8) behaves exactly as I'm used to from Blender 2.79, while at my computer at home (also Manjaro Linux and Blender 2.8) it's the same as described above.

What can I do to get the smooth workflow from Blender 2.79 back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately I stumbled over the solution for this. It has nothing to do with OS or how Blender is installed.

It's simple: If you **click** *Loop Cut* in the tool shelf, you get the crippled behaviour with scrolling and not being able to slide the new cut. But if you use *Loop Cut And Slide* with the **shortcut** <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it behaves as usual. I've tested it with Blender 2.79 and can confirm that you get the same behavior regardless of how you start the tool.

Comment: Still happening in v2.9

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine for me. Try loading factory settings. File>>Defaults>>Load Factory Settings

Comment: No change. I even tested it with a fresh 2.8 download from blender.org.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem one solution I've found is going to edit in the top right > preferences > Keymap. In the search bar put 'r', scroll down till you're under mesh. Remove the key bind linked to 'ctrl r'.

After that while in edit mode press 'ctrl e', right click 'loop cut and slide' and change the shortcut to 'ctrl r'. For me that has worked and I haven't experienced the same problem after.